# Transitive relations on a set of n elements

Tags: equivalence-relations

How to find out the total number of transitive relations in a set of n elements? I am facing a problem in finding all the possible cases, is it not possible to find all cases? If not possible, why?

Comment: Values are given in http://oeis.org/A006905  No formula is given and only terms up to $n=18$ are given.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation#Counting_transitive_relations) that no general formula that counts transitive relations is known.

Of course, for any particular $n$ you can just find all of them by brute force, but that may take a lot of effort even for smallish $n$s -- even for four elements there are thousands of possible transitive relations.

Comment: Can we state why no formula exists without any reference to Wikipedia?

Comment: @user3209588: As far as I know, we can't state that no formula _exists_, with or without reference to Wikipedia -- just that none is _known_.